# How can I get the R of this diagram with circutikz?

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

I am tring to draw this picture

[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) to[R={$R$}] (3,0) coordinate (M) to[L, l={$L,r$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (6,0) to[variable capacitor,l={$C$}]  (8,0) coordinate (B);
    \path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,M/-90,B/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:3.5mm) node{$\p$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

How can I get R in the form of the first picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use europeanresistors, as global option:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
        \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) to[R={$R$}] (3,0) coordinate (M) to[L, l={$L,r$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (6,0) to[variable      capacitor,l={$C$}]  (8,0) coordinate (B);
        \path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,M/-90,B/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:3.5mm) node{$\p$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For a single circuit:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}, european resistors]
            \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) to[R={$R$}] (3,0) coordinate (M) to[L, l={$L,r$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (6,0) to[variable      capacitor,l={$C$}]  (8,0) coordinate (B);
            \path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,M/-90,B/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:3.5mm) node{$\p$}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For a single resistor:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
            \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) to[R={$R$}, european resistors] (3,0) coordinate (M) to[L, l={$L,r$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (6,0) to[variable      capacitor,l={$C$}]  (8,0) coordinate (B);
            \path foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,M/-90,B/-90}{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:3.5mm) node{$\p$}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[@Edson answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659163/38080) is the correct one, but I can't resist adding this --- why don't you use the "poles" mechanism to add the dots instead of the complicated thing with the separate path?

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{european resistors}% preferred way to set global options, circuitkz has too many package options...
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw (0,0) node[below]{$A$} to[R={$R$}, *-*] (3,0) node[below]{$M$}
              to[L, l={$L,r$}, inductors/width=1.4,inductors/coils=11] (6,0)
              to[variable capacitor,l={$C$}, -*]  (8,0) node[below]{$B$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am new to circuitikz, thank you for your answer.